# Word for 'not to self loathe'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, verbs, antonyms

To hate yourself is called to 'self loathe'. What would be a word for 'not to hate yourself' or an antonym for self-loathe?

Comment: *Loathing yourself* may be nominalized as *self-loathing*, but we don't ordinarily backform constructions like this to verbs; we don't use **self loathe* as a verb.

Comment: It depends on how far away from hate you want to get - self-acceptance and narcissism are both valid as antonyms to self-loathing.

Comment: What @Lawrence said. The question is unclear (not specific enough). Is the  opposite of self-loathing that you want self-hating, self-acceptance, or self-love? Unclear.

Comment: "take pride in yourself"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

'**take pride in yourself**' ,  't**ake pride in oneself**', '**be proud of who you are**'

Pride is a word that doesn't have extreme boastful connotations when used this way.

> ***pride*** - noun [google link](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=pride)
>
> 1.
>   a feeling or deep pleasure or satisfaction derived from one's own achievements, the achievements of those with whom one is closely associated, or from qualities or possessions that are widely admired.
>
> "*the team was bursting with pride after recording a sensational victory*"
>
> synonyms:  pleasure, joy, delight, gratification, fulfillment, satisfaction, a sense of achievement
>
> "*take pride in a good job well done*"

You could also simply use '**proud**' to describe someone the opposite of self-loathing, depending on how much you wanted to emphasize that part of a person's nature.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer would be [self-love](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-love); however, one could be said to have good [self-esteem](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-esteem), meaning they think highly of themselves, thus being an antonym to self-loathing. You could also say the person takes [pride](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pride) in themselves or what they do, thus implying they do not loathe themselves, although it is not a direct antonym (someone may be proud of what they do and still loathe themselves).

Answer (score 0):

The closest word I can think of is 'vainglory'. Though I doubt it is used much in modern English.

Comment: vainglorious is very much in use in good feature writing, for instance.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As our site values answers which are *definitive*, your contribution could be improved by excerpting a dictionary definition, providing examples, or otherwise explaining *why* you suggest this word. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.